# Import PyDeadObjectError with wx version 3.0.3

Tags: wxpython

Using wxPython 3.0.3 I am unable to import PyDeadObjectError. 
I believe when I had 3.0 installed, this was not a problem. 
I'm getting a "cannot import name" error.

```
BsMBP:tests bem$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
>>> import wx
>>> wx.version()
'3.0.3.dev1836+f764b32 osx-cocoa (phoenix)'
>>> 
>>> import PyDeadObjectError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyDeadObjectError
>>> 
>>> from wx._core import PyDeadObjectError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name PyDeadObjectError
>>> 
>>> exit()
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the Migration Guide (at http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#wx-pydeadobjecterror-runtimeerror) the ugly hack that generated that exception is no longer needed, so the exception class has been removed.   Now if you try to access a proxy object for a deleted C++ object a `RuntimeError` is raised instead.  Or you can test the window in an `if` statement if you are expecting that it may have been deleted and avoid getting the exception at all.

Comment: Thanks, I will try something like if wx.version() < '3.0.3':
        from wx._core import PyDeadObjectError

Comment: You can use something like  `if 'phoenix' not in wx.PlatformInfo: ...`